# Xamarin Forms CollectionView Select All Items

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection, collectionview

I am using the multi-platform Xamarin forms, and I want to be able to click a button and select all the items inside a `collectionview`.

I have :

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionList" SelectionMode="Multiple"
                            SelectionChanged="RowSelected"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding ContentList}">
```

and inside the cs file:

```
ObservableCollection ContentList = //list made in an earlier method, this is confirmed working
collectionList.SelectedItems= ContentList; //executes on the button click event
```

However that does not work as **SelectedItems** requires an **IList** which does not accept normal **List** or **ObservableCollection**. I also tried setting the **SelectedItems** to collectionList.ItemsSource (the collectionview source) but that gave the same type error which is `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<object>'`

What I have currently working is that the `collectionview` populates with data, and multiple items can be manually selected by the user. This returns me the items that were tapped. I cannot get the view to select everything programmatically though.

I have searched all over and I haven't seen any posts trying to do this, what is the best approach to making a "select all" button for collectionviews?

Edit: The problem was that my list had a defined class as the list type and it needed to be of type `object` as listed in the accepted answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this and it works

```
collectionList.SelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<object>(ContentList);
```

there are undoubtedly other approaches, but not that I can think of on a Sunday afternoon

Comment: That does not work either as adding the ToList() operator converts the data to the **List** type, which as mentioned in the original question is not supported by an **IList** and will give an implicit conversion error

Comment: `List` inherits from `IList`.  What is the **specific** error you are getting?

Comment: **"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<object>'** is the error

Comment: It seems it didn't compile because I had it as a custom type instead of just `object` .  That made the difference thanks for the help.